# For each statement not working correctly

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I am trying to find each record that containts a certain reference number and then for each record assign it to a session so that it can be added to a PDF. When I run the code below it just executes for 1 reference number even though there may be 3 records I need to get data from. Any idea why it is not execting it for each record? TIA

```
      cmd = New SqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = Con
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Physician First Name], [Physician Last Name], [Recipient Primary Business Street Address Line 1], [Recipient City], [Recipient State], [Recipient Zip Code] FROM tblData WHERE ReferenceNumber = @ReferenceNumber"
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ReferenceNumber", (ReferenceTextBox.Text)))

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    For Each NPIlookup In reader

                If (reader.Read()) Then

                    Session("DoctorFirstName") = reader(0)


                End If
                Session("PDF") &= Session("DoctorFirstName")

            Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how a DataReader works

When you enumerate over a reader, you enumerate over the collection of fields for the current record, not over all records. You need to calll reader.Read() to get the next record, then either get a specifig field with the [Item property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy.aspx), get the value cast to a specific type using eg. GetReader,  or iterate over the reader's fields with For Each.

Check the [reader's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) here for an example.

To read specific fields you need to write something like this:

```
While reader.Read()
    Dim firstName=reader.GetString(0)
    ...
End While
```

To iterate over the fields

```
While reader.Read()
    For Each value as Object in reader
        ...
    Next        
End While
```

Comment: *When you enumerate over a reader, you enumerate over the collection of fields for the current record, not over all records.*  This is wrong. When you enumerate over a `SqlDataReader` (or `OracleDataReader`), you enumerate over all records. There's no need to use the `Read()` method. The problem with OPs code is to call `Read()` while already enumerating all records.

Comment: Ouch, you are right. I got confused by Item(). I think it's obvious I never read data this way :).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually, I think very few people do. It's a common misconceptions :-)

Answer (score 5):

The `reader.Read()` in your `for each` loop advances the reader to the next record, skipping the one you're interested in.

You shouldn't modify the collection (in this case, the reader) during the `for each` loop.

Comment: This is the right answer. But I think *modify the collection* should be read *advance the interator while already iterating the sequence with `For Each`* or something like that, since nothing is actually modified.